# Marketing Cloud Connect - change email address

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I have a question about Marketing Cloud Connect:

On Marketing Cloud I would like to change these following fields for API USER:

1. Reply email address
2. Notification email address.

On the Salesforce CRM I would like to change the email address of tracking user used for Marketing Cloud Connect.

To do this, should you first disconnect Marketing Cloud Connect or not? Could there be impacts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user metadata fields you mentioned will not have an impact on the connect if they are updated. If you were changing the Integration user or CRM user's login ID then there would be an issue.